# $ |b-aX|^2=0$ for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, least-squares

Let $b,a$ be $1\times 3$ vectors and $X$ be $3 \times 3$.

If my calculations are correct this leads to $b^Tb-2b^TaX+X^Ta^TaX$  . How can approach this?

EDIT: Given X is an orthogonal matrix $3 \times 3$, take $|b-Xa|^2=0$. for b,a $3 \times 1$ . This leads to: $b^Tb-2b^TXa+a^Ta$. Now everything is a scalar right? X=?

Comment: Your dimensions do not make sense.  If $b$ and $aX$ are $1 \times 3$ then $||b-aX||^2 = (b-aX)(b-aX)^T$.  So $bb^T$ is a scalar but $b^Tb$ is not. Then, it is not clear what you want to do to "approach this" problem.

Comment: It is not a scalar. $\|b-aX\|^2 = (b-aX)^T(b-aX)$ so every term of my above sum is a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Comment: What is meant by $||\cdot||$?  Is it a norm? I assumed you wanted to use a standard Euclidean norm.  Or do you use $|\cdot|$ as a determinant?  Do you feel it is possible to determine the answers to these clarification questions based on what you have provided?

Comment: check edit, I mean the norm

Comment: I see you have switched the notation now.  It looks like you are given vectors $a,b$ and you want to find a matrix $X$ that solves $Xa=b$, is this correct?

Comment: that is exactly the problem , yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76462/discussion-between-michael-and-paramar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the inner product on row vectors defined by $\langle x,y\rangle=xy^T$, the equation $|b-aX|^2=0$ is equivalent to $b=aX$.

If $X$ is orthogonal, then it is invertible and the above is also equivalent to $a=bX^T$.

Nothing more can be said except that the norms of $a$ and $b$ are the same: indeed,
$$
|b|^2=|aX|^2=(aX)(aX)^T=aXX^Ta^T=aa^T=|a|^2
$$

Conversely, given two row vectors $a$ and $b$ such that $|a|=|b|$ there exist *infinitely many* orthogonal matrices $X$ such that $b=aX$.